# What is meant by the composition of maps?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRfaz.png)

Hi all, I would like to seek clarification with regards to what does it mean by 'map of post-composition with f.' (Please refer to the image in the link above.)

To my understanding, it means that we have a collection of all maps from T to X and another collection from T to Y and now we are trying to map from every element in Maps(T,X) to Maps (T,Y) so it like mapping a map to map instead.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me in solving this problem.

Hi I am the original poster of this question. So far I have managed to show [the following](http://postimg.org/image/6p5gx8onv/).

Can anyone help to verify if my working is correct. As for showing <=, my prof suggested letting T be a singleton, can anyone enlighten me the rational on why should we let T be a singleton?

Comment: As for the clarification: yes, you're right. But there's more: here we know what the map between maps is: to $\phi$ is mapped $f\circ\phi$, which is important here.

Comment: Do you also want help with the problem itself? If yes, what are your thoughts so far? How do you prove that a mapping is an injection?

Comment: Hi so far I have managed to prove =>, that is assuming the f is injective and showing that Maps(T,X) to Maps(T,Y) is injective too.

But I have trouble showing <=. Suppose we let T be any singleton, can we say that the map from T to X will be injective? I am stuck at this part here. Would greatly appreciate some help

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a set and let $\phi_1,\phi_2\in\text{Maps}(T,X)$ with $\phi_1\neq\phi_2$.

That means that $\phi_1(t)\neq\phi_2(t)$ for some $t\in T$.

Then injectivity of $f$ implies that $f(\phi_1(t))\neq f(\phi_2(t))$ hence $f\circ\phi_1\neq f\circ\phi_2$.

Proved is now:$$f\text{ is injective}\implies\Phi_T\text{ is injective}$$

and this can be done for *any* set $T$.

Conversely if $f$ is not injective then choose for $T=X$.

There are elements $x_1,x_2\in X$ with $x_1\neq x_2$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Now for $\phi$ take the identity on $X$ and let $\psi$ be described by $x\mapsto x$ if $x\neq x_1$ and $x\mapsto x_2$ otherwise.

Then $\phi\neq\psi$ but $f\circ\phi=f\circ\psi$.

This proves that $\Phi_X$ is not injective.

You can also choose for other sets $T$ to prove this. It is enough if $T$ contains $2$ distinct elements. In one case both are sent to $x_1$, in the other one is sent to $x_1$ and the other to $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

To the question in topic: the composition of maps is another map, defined this way:
$$
(f\circ \phi)(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}= f(\phi(x))
$$
We take first the value of $\phi$ in $x$ and then the value of $f$ in the value of $\phi$, $\phi(x)$. Of course $f$ and $\phi$ must be defined on "compatible" sets, like in your example: codomain of $\phi$ is the domain of $f$ (some would say that it is enough that $\operatorname{codom} \phi \subset \operatorname{dom} f$, which is true in a way, but not from a strict set-theoretic point of view.)

Some hints for the problem: if $f$ is not an injection, then there are $x_1,\ x_2\in X$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Let's say that $T=\{0\}$, so the maps $\phi$ are defined only on one element. Now, how can we define $\phi_1,\ \phi_2\!:\{0\}\to X$ using $x_1$ and $x_2$, so that $f\circ \phi_1 = f\circ\phi_2$, that is: $f(\phi_1(0)) = f(\phi_2(0))$? How about for other sets $T$?